# Redefinition of typedef is a C11 feature

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm trying to create a header file as such:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

typedef void (^RevealBlock)();

@interface BFTasksViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate> {
@private
    RevealBlock _revealBlock;
}

- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title withRevealBlock:(RevealBlock)revealBlock;

@end
```

But I get this warning:

> Redefinition of typedef 'RevealBlock' is a C11 feature

Is this something to be worried about? I'm looking at the [GHSidebarNav project](https://github.com/gresrun/GHSidebarNav), which seems to use it just fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must have declared `RevealBlock` somewhere else, as i don't see any import other than UIKit/UIKit.h, check you project `.pch` file for conflicting headers (or could it be that you removed some headers to make the snippet shorter ?).

Comment: Thanks! So I used it in the app delegate's header file and I think that's what was triggering the warning. Instead, I moved the definition to the .pch file and deleted all other definitions.

Answer (score 3):

> Is this something to be worried about?

If you are compiling a C or ObjC program and the compiler does not support C11, then the compiler should reject the program (GCC 4.2-Apple/LLVM as an example you or somebody using your program may be using). Note that C++ has supported multiple definitions for many years.

Of course, these definitions which appear in multiple files must always match where you use them as the same type. Otherwise, the compiler may set the parameters up incorrectly before the call is made.

Answer (score 1):

Change the "C Language Dialect" building option to "gnu11" or "compiler default" for Xcode 11.

Comment: I like this approach, in my case this building option was non-standard.